# Relations in entities in Symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to figure out the relations in Symfony but it doesn't work

I have a Livre entity and an Auteur entity. A Livre can only have one Auteur but an Auteur can have multiple Livre. Here's what I did:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\LivreRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=LivreRepository::class)
 */
class Livre
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $uuid;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $couverture;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10000)
     */
    private $resume;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $nombrePages;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $dateParution;

     /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Auteur::class, inversedBy="auteur")
    */
    private $auteur;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUuid(): ?string
    {
        return $this->uuid;
    }

    public function setUuid(string $uuid): self
    {
        $this->uuid = $uuid;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function setNom(string $nom): self
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCouverture(): ?string
    {
        return $this->couverture;
    }

    public function setCouverture(?string $couverture): self
    {
        $this->couverture = $couverture;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getResume(): ?string
    {
        return $this->resume;
    }

    public function setResume(string $resume): self
    {
        $this->resume = $resume;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNombrePages(): ?int
    {
        return $this->nombrePages;
    }

    public function setNombrePages(?int $nombrePages): self
    {
        $this->nombrePages = $nombrePages;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDateParution(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->dateParution;
    }

    public function setDateParution(?\DateTimeInterface $dateParution): self
    {
        $this->dateParution = $dateParution;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAuteur(): ?Auteur
    {
        return $this->auteur;
    }

    public function setAuteur(int $auteur): self
    {
        $this->auteur = $auteur;

        return $this;
    }
}


<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\AuteurRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=AuteurRepository::class)
 */
class Auteur
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=36)
     */
    private $uuid;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $prenom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Livre", mappedBy="livre")
     */
    private $livres;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->livres = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Product[]
     */
    public function getLivres(): Collection
    {
        return $this->livres;
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUuid(): ?string
    {
        return $this->uuid;
    }

    public function setUuid(string $uuid): self
    {
        $this->uuid = $uuid;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPrenom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->prenom;
    }

    public function setPrenom(string $prenom): self
    {
        $this->prenom = $prenom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function setNom(string $nom): self
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Also, I guess that's important, in my database, Livre has a column named auteur_id

When I access Livre, I get all the informations on this entity, and an object Auteur with all its properties. The property id shows but not the others. And it's kind of the same the other way around : when I access Auteur, it shows an empty collection of Livre, where it should show me all the Livre linked to Auteur.

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I can correct this so everything works please?

---

This is how I access the properties :

```
$livre = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Livre::class)->findOneBy(array('uuid' => $uuid));

$idAuteur = $livre->getAuteur()->getId();

$auteur = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Auteur::class)->findOneBy(array('id' => $idAuteur));
```

and here's the result when I print those :

```
App\Entity\Livre {#697 ▼
  -id: 2
  -uuid: "33bd3ee1-774a-4f0a-9c9d-22d7ad1b37b3"
  -nom: "Shadow and Bone"
  -couverture: "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81QtYjs-6qL.jpg"
  -resume: """
    Surrounded by enemies, the once-great nation of Ravka has been torn in two by the Shadow Fold, a swath of near impenetrable darkness crawling with monsters who  ▶
     
 
 
    Alina Starkov has never been good at anything. But when her regiment is attacked on the Fold and her best friend is brutally injured, Alina reveals a dormant po ▶
     
 
 
    Yet nothing in this lavish world is what it seems. With darkness looming and an entire kingdom depending on her untamed power, Alina will have to confront the s ▶
    """
  -nombrePages: 358
  -dateParution: DateTime @1338854400 {#695 ▶}
  -auteur: Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Auteur {#716 ▼
    +__isInitialized__: false
    -id: 6
    -uuid: null
    -prenom: null
    -nom: null
    -livres: null
     …2
  }
}

Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Auteur {#716 ▼
  +__isInitialized__: true
  -id: 10
  -uuid: "4a3db201-11dc-4f62-af8b-aa0301ae8974"
  -prenom: "Amy"
  -nom: "Ewing"
  -livres: Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection {#707 ▼
    -snapshot: []
    -owner: Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Auteur {#716 …2}
    -association: array:15 [ …15]
    -em: Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager {#529 …11}
    -backRefFieldName: "auteur"
    -typeClass: Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata {#646 …}
    -isDirty: false
    #collection: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#733 ▼
      -elements: []
    }
    #initialized: false
  }
   …2
}
```

Comment: Your `inversedBy` and `mappedBy` seem off. They're supposed to contain the name of the property from the *other* class which contains the relation. `$auteur` is not inversed by `auteur`, it's inversed by `$livres` from the `Auteur` class.

Comment: Hi, I did what you said and now I can access auteur in livre only if I made a request like this : $idAuteur = $livre->getAuteur()->getId();
        $auteur = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Auteur::class)->findOneBy(array('id' => $idAuteur)); otherwise it doesn't appear in livre (which i don't really understand but ok). And I still can't access livres in auteur :/

Comment: Did you fix the `mappedBy` argument as well?

Comment: Yes, in auteur I did * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Livre", mappedBy="auteur") and in livre I did * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Auteur::class, inversedBy="livres")

Comment: Then, by everything I'm seeing in your question, it should work. Can you edit your question to show how you're accessing these properties?

Comment: Sure! It'll be done in a minute

Comment: As I suspected, you're observing it in a dump. The thing is that by default, these relations are lazy loaded, meaning their properties will be filled only when you actually try to fetch them. Try using individual properties, you should be getting their values.

Comment: Wow, you're right! Well thank you so much for your help, I'm so glad I'm gonna be able to access these :D